# Did Kili try to steal something from Tauriel?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-hobbit, the-desolation-of-smaug

In [The Hobbit: The Desolation of Smaug](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1170358/) when the dwarfs were imprisoned by elves, Kili talks about the talisman (which was given to him by his mother) to Tauriel. During the conversation, the talisman slips out of Kili's hand while he's tossing it in the air (maybe Kili did it on purpose) and Tauriel stops the talisman with her foot and as soon as Tauriel bends to take the talisman, Kili behind the bars reaches out for Tauriel as if he's trying to snatch something from her. I thought it was the keys Kili tried to steal but obviously it's not the keys.

Did Kili try to steal something from Tauriel?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since Tauriel is a character invented by Jackson and she didn't appear in the book the only source of information that we have is the film itself.

After rewatching the scene I'd say (but this is mostly a personal interpretation) that Kili wanted to receive his talisman back, because there isn't any hint that he may have been trying to steal something from Tauriel (the only thing he could have been interested in were the keys, but you already ruled out that possibility) and he seems genuinely worried about his talisman, it doesn't look like he let it fall on purpose.

Comment: +1. It's a natural reaction when someone else handles a very precious item to you, to reach out for it. Kili was merely reaching for the item, and then realized he either couldn't get it first or was out of reach.

Comment: Will have to rewatch, I thought he was going for the keys, but was just lame about it.